# Die Durchführung der dt. Rechtschreibreform von 1996 (und der Folgejahre)

Tags: history, reformed-orthography

Was war richtig, was war falsch an der Rechtschreibreform von 1996 (und der Folgereformen)? Was müsste man tun, um eine Rechtschreibreform optimal, d.h. mit minimalen Konflikten, durchzuführen? Wieviel muss "durchgepeitscht" werden, und wo hat "das Volk" mitzureden?

Comment: Es gibt in dem Sinne kein richtig und kein falsch. Es gibt nur Leute, denen die Reform oder Teile der Reform nicht passt und andere, die es begrüssen. Aber wie willst du beurteilen, ob es richtig ist "dass" oder "daß" zu schreiben? Man kann in Frage stellen, ob man dann nicht auch "Strasse" anstatt "Straße" schreiben sollte. - Optimal wird es nie geben. Die Sprache lebt und so kommen immer wieder neue Gründe, warum die Sprache geändert wird oder werden muss.

Comment: Na, wenn sich so etwas 15 Jahre hinzieht und soviel Nacharbeit nötig war, gibt es vielleicht doch ein *falsch* (?)

Comment: Ich bin zu der Einschätzung gelangt, dass eine Rechtschreibreform nur durch »Durchpeitschen« funktionieren kann, sobald sie allgemeine Änderungen einführt (siehe auch [hier](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/do-central-language-regulation-bodies-accelerate-or-inhibit-orthography-changes)). Ansonsten finde ich diese Fragen aus diversen Gründen hier unpassend (off-topic, meinungslastig, immer noch zu breit).

Comment: Die Frage ist viel zu weit gefasst und die unterschiedlichen Teile könnten leicht von verschiedenen Antworten jeweils am besten beantwortet werden.

Comment: Wenn ich noch weiter zerhacke, endet das aber in Antworten wie "Wie A in Antwort zu Frage 3 Absatz 3 und B in Antwort zu Frage 7 Absatz 2 schon geschrieben hat, ..."

Comment: Also zumindest die inhaltliche Kritik an der Reform und die Kritik an ihrer Durchführung sind recht gut trennbar. Erstere ist so allgemein viel zu meinungslastig und kann weiter aufgedröselt werden, bis man bei Fragen angelangt wie »Was sind die Vor- und Nahchteile der heyseschen s-Schreibung?«, die dann auch tatsächlich konstruktiv beantwortbar sind. Zweitere Frage ist eher was für den Linguistik-SE, wenn überhaupt.

Comment: Leute, wie soll ich's noch anders ausdrücken? Eine grundsätzliche Reflektion der Reform als Ganzes in ein paar Sätzen anhand von Fakten ist doch sicher in diesem Forum hier gut aufgehoben war meine Intention. Die Antwort von Tatjana Heuser trifft es z.B. schon genau richtig. Ich verstehe das Downgevote leider nicht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zur (kritischen) Beurteilung der Rechtschreibreform hat [Theodor Ickler](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodor_Ickler) ausführlich und kompetent geschrieben, daher verweise ich an dieser Stelle auf seine [Publikationen](http://www.sprachwissenschaft.uni-erlangen.de/personen/daten/index.shtml/theodor-ickler.shtml). Als Beteiligter an den Diskussionen (Theodor Ickler war bis Anfang 2006 Mitglied im Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung) kennt er auch die besondere Problematik, die Interessen, die in eine solche Diskussion einfließen, und die daraus resultierenden Konflikte, wegen der er den Rat letztendlich verlassen hat.

- [Die sogenannte Rechtschreibreform (pdf, 1997)](http://www.vernuenftig-schreiben.de/dokumente/ickler_die_sogenannte_rechtschreibreform.pdf)
- [Regelungsgewalt. Hintergründe der Rechtschreibreform (pdf, 2001)](http://www.vernuenftig-schreiben.de/dokumente/ickler_regelungsgewalt.pdf)

---

(in Bearbeitung - aus dem Regal auf den Schreibtisch)

- Kopke, Wolfgang: **Rechtschreibreform und Verfassungsrecht** : schulrechtliche, persönlichkeitsrechtliche und kulturverfassungsrechtliche Aspekte einer Reform der deutschen Orthographie / von Wolfgang Kopke. - Tübingen : Mohr. - 1995 (1995). - Zugl.: Jena, Univ., Diss., 1995
- Mentrup, Wolfgang, 1935-: **Stationen der jüngeren Geschichte der Orthographie und ihrer Reform seit 1933** : zur Diskussion, Texttradition und -rezeption / Wolfgang Mentrup. Unter Mitwirkung von Kerstin Steiger. - Tübingen : Narr. - 2007 (2007). - (Studien zur deutschen Sprache ; 29)
- Deutsche Akademie für Sprache und Dichtung, Darmstadt: **Zur Reform der deutschen Rechtschreibung** : ein Kompromißvorschlag / hrsg. von der Deutschen Akademie für Sprache und Dichtung. - 1. Aufl.. - Göttingen : Wallstein-Verl.. - 2003 (2003)
- Internationaler Arbeitskreis für Orthographie: **Deutsche Rechtschreibung : Vorschläge zu ihrer Neuregelung** / hrsg. vom Internationalen Arbeitskreis für Orthographie. - 2., durchges. Aufl.. - Tübingen : Narr. - 1993 (1993)
- Ickler, Theodor, 1944-: **Falsch ist richtig** : ein Leitfaden durch die Abgründe der Rechtschreibreform ; [ein Leitfaden durch die Abgründe der Schlechtschreibreform] / Theodor Ickler. - München : Droemer. - 2006 (2006)
- Ickler, Theodor, 1944-: **Rechtschreibreform in der Sackgasse** : neue Dokumente und Kommentare / Theodor Ickler. - 1. Aufl.. - St. Goar : Leibniz-Verl.. - 2004 (2004)
  Kritischer Kommentar zur "Neuregelung der deutschen Rechtschreibung"
- Ickler, Theodor, 1944-: **Die sogenannte Rechtschreibreform** : ein Schildbürgerstreich / Theodor Ickler. - 1. Aufl.. - St. Goar : Leibniz-Verl.. - 1997 (1997)
- Ickler, Theodor, 1944-: **Kritischer Kommentar zur "Neuregelung der deutschen Rechtschreibung"** : mit einem Anhang zur "Mannheimer Anhörung". - 2., durchges. und erw. Aufl.. - Erlangen [u.a.] : Palm & Enke. - 1999 (1999). - (Erlanger Studien ; 116)

Comment: Vielleicht kannst Du uns noch eine prägnante Stelle aus den Publikationen von Ickler zitieren (`>`)? Das würde Deine Antwort ziemlich aufmotzen ;)

Comment: Ja, da ist noch deutlich mehr zu schreiben - sowohl was den inhaltlichen Aspekt der Frage angeht, als auch den politischen Aspekt betreffend. Jetzt bin ich aber erst einmal ein paar Stunden offline, daher bis zum nächsten edit ersteinmal ein Startpunkt zum weiterlesen.